# offsetWidth not same in different Browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a difference of `1px` between FF and Chrome in `element.offsetWidth`.

I have been reading trying to understand the problem. Tried to [reset the CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), tried to move the element away from near the screen borders (I remember old IE was inacurrate if 10px near the screen broder). Found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516030/different-value-of-offsetwidth-in-firefox-and-chrome) about FF needing a setTimeout, but no answer about why...

Still no solution. I'm looking to understand/fix it with vanilla JS or CSS.

Question:

Why is this and what can I do in my CSS to get the values consistent?

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f35j2/show/**

html

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 203px; height: 203px;">
    <div id="inner" style="width: 50%; height: 50%; margin: auto; display: block;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The width of the inner element is a non integer. FF and Chrome are rounding the number differently. You can get the exact width by using inner.getBoundingClientRect().width (which is 101.5)

This is because the parent element is 203px. Not 202 or 204.

Comment: Interesting... `+1`. Is there something that can be done to correct this besides making if/else script for each browser to compensate this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by if/else script. As mentioned in my answer, you can still get the exact width if needed. If you want to change the width in all browsers to be equal, you don't need an if/else script. Otherwise you can change the parent container to have an even width (if possible).

Comment: Eman, the parent Element has odd width and I cannot change that. By if/else script I mean feature detect browser and compensate the round up/down each browser does so I get a consistent number in every browser, which is my goal.

Comment: You wouldn't need an if/else for that. You could just set the width constantly in all browsers. E.g.

       var inner = document.getElementById('inner');
       inner.style.width = Math.floor(inner.getBoundingClientRect().width)+'px';
       alert(inner.offsetWidth);

I guess that should work.

Comment: Eman, I want the output width to be consistent in different browsers. User might do a resize so I cannot force the width to a fixed number.

Comment: If the 203 pixels of the parent element is fixed, resizing won't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

When I opened your jsfiddle link in chrome and firefox and analysed the values what I got is:

- In both browsers (Firefox and Chrome) the CSS calculate value of height and width (for #inner) is same i.e. 101.5px
- While drawing the element, FF uses round down for fractional values. Thus, the drawn height and width is 101px.
- But Chrome is using round up/down to nearest integer for height. i.e. any value between 100.5 to 101.4999 will be treated as 101, and 101.5 to 102.4999 will be 102
- But for width the calculation is only round down. i.e. any value from 101 to 101.9999 will be treated as 101

Refer the snapshot below
[image: snapshot] .
 You can exercise the same with boundary values (e.g. 101.4999, 101.9999) to get more idea of this.

Comment: Interesting `+1`. Where/how do you get float values in FF?

Comment: @Rikard, You can see this in FF also using developer tools (F12) >> Inspector. See the difference in values under _Computed_ and _Box Model_ tabs.