# Hide element if scrolled to maximum of container

Tags: javascript, jquery, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

I worked with this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


// Show left gradient if scrolled x value is greater than 0

  $("#scroll-area").scroll(function() {
    if ($("#scroll-area").scrollLeft() > 0) {
      $("#left").css("display", "block");
    }


// Hide left gradient if scrolled x value is 0

    if ($("#scroll-area").scrollLeft() == 0) {
      $("#left").css("display", "none");
    }


// Calculate with of the scroll area

    var fullWidth = $('#scroll-area')[0].scrollWidth;


// Doesn't work: Hide right gradient if scrolled to maximum

    if ($("#scroll-area").scrollLeft() == fullWidth) {
      $("#right").css("display", "none");
    }


// Doesn't work: Show gradient if scrolled less than maximum

    if ($("#scroll-area").scrollLeft() < fullWidth) {
      $("#right").css("display", "block");
    }


  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}

#scroll-area {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

#left,
#right {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
}

#left {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, orange 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

#right {
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, orange 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
  <div id="scroll-area">
    <div id="text">Please scroll horizontally to the right side, and back again. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you scroll horizontally to the end of the `#text` element, the gradient on the right side should be hidden. If you scroll to the left side again, the gradient should be shown again.

Has anyone an idea how to program that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to subtract the `offsetWidth` from the `scrollWidth`:

```
var fullWidth = $('#scroll-area')[0].scrollWidth - $('#scroll-area')[0].offsetWidth - 1  // -1 for browser compatibility
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


// Show left gradient if scrolled x value is greater than 0

  $("#scroll-area").scroll(function() {
    if ($("#scroll-area").scrollLeft() > 0) {
      $("#left").css("display", "block");
    }


// Hide left gradient if scrolled x value is 0

    if ($("#scroll-area").scrollLeft() == 0) {
      $("#left").css("display", "none");
    }


// Calculate with of the scroll area
    
    var fullWidth = $('#scroll-area')[0].scrollWidth - $('#scroll-area')[0].offsetWidth - 1;


// Doesn't work: Hide right gradient if scrolled to maximum

    if ($("#scroll-area").scrollLeft() >= fullWidth) {
      $("#right").css("display", "none");
    }


// Doesn't work: Show gradient if scrolled less than maximum

    if ($("#scroll-area").scrollLeft() < fullWidth) {
      $("#right").css("display", "block");
    }

  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}

#scroll-area {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

#left,
#right {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
}

#left {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, orange 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

#right {
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, orange 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
  <div id="scroll-area">
    <div id="text">Please scroll horizontally to the right side, and back again. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey! The right gradient stays if I scroll to the right side. This should disappear if you reach the maximum.

Comment: Hmm.  Wierd.  It disappears on my end if you scroll all the way to the right.

Comment: I am using macOS. It doesn't work with Google Chrome, but (for whatever reason) with Safari. That's really weird.

Comment: I am on Win 10.  It works on my end using Chrome and Edge.

Comment: Weird. The solution of @Evren seems to work. Where exactly do you see the problem about this code?

Comment: I deleted my comment from his answer.  Since it seems to work for you, maybe it is isolated to my PC.  His answer is good but it just doesn't work on my machine.

Comment: Oh, that's also problematic. If it doesn't work on Windows maybe. Hm ... :(

Comment: Looks like different browsers calculate width differently.  I found this helpful post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104905/offsetwidth-not-same-in-different-browsers  You could try to use a value 1px smaller for the comparison to address it.  I doubt your users would notice the 1px difference.  I updated my answer, see if that works on your end.

Comment: It works, thank you! I posted an additional question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71669678/only-show-elements-if-container-is-scrollable – Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Could you please tell me how did you decide to choose this answer after accepting my answer as accepted one and i do not even have up vote for solution? I can not see any difference (soution copied from my answer) in code except -1 which does not change anything? @Anna_B

Comment: Hey, @Tim told me that your solution didn't work on his computer.

Answer (score 0):

It should work as you want. Basically i calculate scrollable area in `fullWidth` and compare it with `scrollPosition`

```js
$("#scroll-area").scroll(function() {
  var fullWidth = $('#scroll-area')[0].scrollWidth - $('#scroll-area')[0].clientWidth;
  var scrollPosition = $(this).scrollLeft();
  if (scrollPosition > 0 && scrollPosition <= fullWidth) {
    $("#left").css("display", "block");
    $("#right").css("display", "block");
  } else if (scrollPosition == 0) {
    $("#left").css("display", "none");
    $("#right").css("display", "block");
  } else if (fullWidth <= scrollPosition) {
    $("#left").css("display", "block");
    $("#right").css("display", "none");
  }
  console.log('Scroll pos',scrollPosition);
  console.log('Full width', fullWidth);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}

#scroll-area {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

#left,
#right {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
}

#left {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, orange 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

#right {
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, orange 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
  <div id="scroll-area">
    <div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```