# Only show elements if container is scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, horizontal-scrolling

This is the code:

```js
// if there is something to scroll horizontally then (but only for this container):

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".scroll-area").scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollLeft() > 0) {
      $(".left").css("display", "block");
    }

    if ($(this).scrollLeft() == 0) {
      $(".left").css("display", "none");
    }

    var fullWidth = $(this)[0].scrollWidth - $(this)[0].offsetWidth - 1;

    if ($(this).scrollLeft() >= fullWidth) {
      $(".right").css("display", "none");
    }

    if ($(this).scrollLeft() < fullWidth) {
      $(".right").css("display", "block");
    }

  });
});

// if there is nothing to scroll, don't show the gradients
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container {
  width: 550px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.scroll-area {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
}

.left {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, orange 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.right {
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, orange 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="scroll-area">
    <div class="text">Scroll to right. Gradients are needed. This container works like expected. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="scroll-area">
    <div class="text">This container shouldn't show any gradient because nothing to scroll.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There should be an `if` function added. The logic should be:
Show the gradient(s) only if there is something to scroll horizontally. If not, then hide the gradient(s). It should work with different containers independently on the same web page, and should update if the browser size changes.

Has someone an idea how to code that?

Comment: It seems that your code is doing what you want. Elements should have unique ids, that's the reason the second div isn't working. I recommend changing the ids into classes and loop through that. Including the "left" and "right"

Comment: @shunz19 Oh yeah, sorry. I just changed the IDs to classes. But the second container shows a gradient on the right side. There shouldn't be any gradient because there is nothing to scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to loop thru all the `.scroll-area` elements and hide `.left` and `.right` elements if the scrollbar is visible.  I added couple more containers to demonstrate:

```js
// if there is something to scroll horizontally then (but only for this container):

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".scroll-area").each(function(index) {
    if ($(this)[0].scrollWidth <= $(this)[0].clientWidth) {
      $(this).closest(".container").find(".left").css("display", "none");
      $(this).closest(".container").find(".right").css("display", "none");
    } else {
      $(this).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this)[0].scrollWidth > $(this)[0].clientWidth) {
          if ($(this).scrollLeft() > 0) {
            $(this).closest(".container").find(".left").css("display", "block");
          }

          if ($(this).scrollLeft() == 0) {
            $(this).closest(".container").find(".left").css("display", "none");
          }

          var fullWidth = $(this)[0].scrollWidth - $(this)[0].offsetWidth - 1;

          if ($(this).scrollLeft() >= fullWidth) {
            $(this).closest(".container").find(".right").css("display", "none");
          }

          if ($(this).scrollLeft() < fullWidth) {
            $(this).closest(".container").find(".right").css("display", "block");
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

// if there is nothing to scroll, don't show the gradients
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container {
  width: 550px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.scroll-area {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
}

.left {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, orange 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.right {
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, orange 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="x" class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div id="a" class="scroll-area">
    <div class="text">Scroll to right. Gradients are needed. This container works like expected. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="y" class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div id="b" class="scroll-area">
    <div class="text">This container shouldn't show any gradient because nothing to scroll.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="y" class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div id="b" class="scroll-area">
    <div class="text">This container shouldn't show any gradient because nothing to scroll.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="x" class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div id="a" class="scroll-area">
    <div class="text">Scroll to right. Gradients are needed. This container works like expected. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Tim – I posted here an additional question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71722861/horizontal-scroll-areas-with-buttons-and-gradients – I would be so happy if you could help with that as well

Comment: Hi @Anna_B, I just posted an answer.  See if that works for you.